# NumberLong() in MongoDB && PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

```
db.projects.find()
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("508d4028e60d8c2154a2eb36"), 
  "date" : NumberLong(1351432927), 
  "deadline" : "2012-12-31", 
  "payment" : "100500", 
  "title" : "Project", 
  "userid" : ObjectId("5083677d2f5c849509c3aae6") 
}
```

All right, but in PHP `print_r($find_result)` doesn't show the key "*date*" at all!
Why? And how I can extract value from `NumberLong()` in PHP?

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit or 64 bit environment? Which version of mongodb and php driver are you using? It may be more efficient to use ISODate instead of numberlog to store the date.

Comment: 64 bit.
Unless I need to explicitly insert into the document class MongoInt64()?

Comment: Numeric values will automatically be converted by the PHP driver; you shouldn't have to do any "extraction" for a `NumberLong` value.  As mentioned in the comment above you may want to store this as a [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) for convenience (eg. using Aggregation Framework [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#date-operators)).  If the `date` field isn't showing in your result, there is likely another problem .. can you include the `find()` query you are using?

Comment: $project = $db->projects->findOne(array("_id" => $pid));
    print_r($project);

Comment: what gets printed out in Php?

Comment: @Stennie he may not have turned on http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php#ini.mongo.native-long which will convert these numbers for you to standard ints. This is turned off by default still I think. Though if it doesn't show it at all then it probably is another problem

Comment: @Sammaye: there's mention of running 64-bit in the comment above, so the NumberLongs should  be converted into a double without the `mongo.native-long` setting.  Regardless, that doesn't explain why the field wouldn't be included in the result :-|.